# Justify the use of Fubini in the case where the product space includes $\Omega$

Tags: stochastic-processes, lebesgue-integral, fubini-tonelli-theorems

I have the following process where $B$ is a Brownian motion

$$\int_0^T \frac{B(T)-B(s)}{T-s}ds$$

I want to verify that the expectation exists, but to do so mandates exchange of the integrals via Fubini. How do I prove that

$$\int_{\Omega\times[0,T]}\frac{B(T,\omega)-B(s,\omega)}{T-s}d(\omega,s)<\infty$$

What are the general techniques for proving such results and exactly how do I think about this integral that is also over the space $\Omega$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By Tonelli's Theorem we can write $E\int_0^{T} |\frac {B(T)-B(s)} {T-s}| ds=\int_0^{T} E|\frac {B(T)-B(s)} {T-s}| ds$. To compute $E|\frac {B(T)-B(s)} {T-s}|$ observe that $Y=\frac {B(T)-B(s)} {\sqrt{T-s}}$ has standard normal distribution. Hence  $E|\frac {B(T)-B(s)} {T-s}|=\frac a {\sqrt {T-s}}$ where $a=E|Y|$. Finally $E\int_0^{T} |\frac {B(T)-B(s)} {T-s}| ds=\int_0^{T} \frac a {\sqrt {T-s}}ds$ which is fiite. Now we can apply Fubini's Theorem since $\frac {B(T)-B(s)} {T-s}$ is integrable on the product space.

Comment: How do we know the double integral is finite if both the iterated integrals are finite?

Comment: For the non-negative case that is Tonelli's Theorem (which says that the double integral is same as either of the iterated integrals for non-negative measurable functions on the product space) . I took absolute values to make the integrand nonnegative. @Dole

Comment: Ah of course, thank you :-).